# What is the relationship of Krishna avatar to Jainism?

Tags: rebirth

Do Jain believe Krsna (Vishnu) will become the next and final Thirtankara?    Does that mean Kalki avatar is a Thirtankara?

Comment: I think he is one of the shalaka purusha.